# custom dialog did show up in one activity and did not in other, no errors

Tags: android, dialog

I have a little issue. In my one activity (MainActivity) dialog window (dialog_exit) show up without any problems but in other anctivity (MenuR) it (dialog_podaj) did not. When I click a button the screen become darker and that's all. Nothing else happen. No error is showing.
I think the code is the same, but I can be wrong. I can't see any mistake in my second ancivity code, so this is why I ask You to for help.

This is a first activity (MainActivity), here dialog window works:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        // [...]
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_manin);

            mVisible = true;
            mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controlsM);
            mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_contentM);



            mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    toggle();
                }
            });


            MainActButtons();
        }

        private void MainActButtons(){
            Button button_ng = findViewById(R.id.MainActivity_button_NG);
            Button button_opcje = findViewById(R.id.MainActivity_button_Opcje);
            Button button_wyjscie = findViewById(R.id.MainActivity_button_Wyjscie);

            button_ng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent menu_tryb = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuT.class);
                    startActivity(menu_tryb);
                }
            });

            button_opcje.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.dialogtxt_opcje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            button_wyjscie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DialogEXIT();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

            delayedHide(100);
        }

        private void DialogEXIT(){
            final Dialog dialog_wyjscie = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog_wyjscie.setCancelable(true);
            dialog_wyjscie.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_exit);
            Button dialogbutton_wroc = dialog_wyjscie.findViewById(R.id.dialogExitApp_button_WROC);
            Button dialogbutton_wyjdz = dialog_wyjscie.findViewById(R.id.dialogExitApp_button_WYJDZ);
            dialog_wyjscie.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog_wyjscie.show();

            dialogbutton_wroc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog_wyjscie.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialogbutton_wyjdz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            dialogbutton_wyjdz.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog_wyjscie.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed (){
            DialogEXIT();
        }

        private void toggle() {
            if (mVisible) {
                hide();
            } else {
                show();
            }
        }

        private void hide() {
            // Hide UI first
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.hide();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mVisible = false;


            mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
            mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
        }

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        private void show() {

            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
            mVisible = true;


            mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
            mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
        }


        private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
            mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
            mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
        }
    }
```

Here is a laybout of MainActivity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_contentM"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_button_NG"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_szarp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/MainActivity_logo"
            android:text="@string/text_nowa_gra"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_txt" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_button_Opcje"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_szarp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/MainActivity_button_NG"
            android:text="@string/text_opcje"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_button_Wyjscie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_szarp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:text="@string/text_wyjscie"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_txt" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controlsM"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is dialog_exit layout code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dialogExitApp_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogExitApp_TV_text"
            android:layout_width="325dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text_wyjscie_info"
            android:textColor="@color/dialog_exit_txt_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dialogExitApp_button_WROC"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="35dp"
                android:minWidth="120dp"
                android:text="@string/text_wroc"
                android:textColor="@drawable/button_txt"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dialogExitApp_button_WYJDZ"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="35dp"
                android:minWidth="120dp"
                android:text="@string/text_wyjdz"
                android:textColor="@drawable/button_txt2"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It all works without any issues.

And there is a code of MenuR activity. There is a dialog window that is not working.

```
public class MenuR extends AppCompatActivity {

    int kontrolkaET;
    String textNr = " ";
    // [...]
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_r);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controlsR);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_contentR);

        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        MenuRolaButtons ();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        delayedHide(100);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void MenuRolaButtons (){
        Button button_t1 = findViewById(R.id.MenuR_button_T1);
        Button button_t2 = findViewById(R.id.MenuR_button_T2);
        Button button_wsteczR = findViewById(R.id.MenuR_button_Wstecz);

        button_t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent_tY = new Intent(MenuR.this, MapaT.class);
                startActivity(intent_tY);
            }
        });

        button_t2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String[] inputStringNr = {null};
                final Dialog dialogPodajNr = new Dialog(MenuR.this);
                dialogPodajNr.setCancelable(true);
                dialogPodajNr.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_podaj);
                dialogPodajNr.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                final EditText ETnrRoz = dialogPodajNr.findViewById(R.id.dialogPodajNr_ET_numer);
                Button buttonDialogOK = dialogPodajNr.findViewById(R.id.dialogPodajNr_button_OK);
                kontrolkaET = 0;
                dialogPodajNr.show();

                ETnrRoz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (kontrolkaET == 0) {
                            ETnrRoz.getText().clear();
                            kontrolkaET = 1;
                        }
                    }
                });



                ETnrRoz.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        inputStringNr[0] = s.toString();
                        textNr = inputStringNr[0];
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });

                buttonDialogOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent_Komp = new Intent(MenuR.this, Komp.class);
                        intent_Komp.putExtra("numer_r", textNr);
                        dialogPodajNr.dismiss();
                        startActivity(intent_Komp);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        button_wsteczR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;


        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;


        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }


    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

MenuR layout code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".MenuR"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_contentR">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/MenuR_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MenuR_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MenuR_button_T1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_szarp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/MenuR_logo"
            android:text="@string/text_t1"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_txt" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MenuR_button_T2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_szarp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/MenuR_button_T1"
            android:text="@string/text_t2"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MenuR_button_Wstecz"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_szarp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:text="@string/text_wstecz"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_txt" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controlsR"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And dialog_podaj layout code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dialogPodajNr_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/dialogPodajNr_guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/dialogPodajNr_guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/dialogPodajNr_guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/dialogPodajNr_guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogPodajNr_TV_text"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_proszeNr"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/dialog_exit_txt_color"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dialogPodajNr_ET_numer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="@string/text_dots"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            android:textColor="@color/dialog_exit_txt_color"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialogPodajNr_button_OK"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:text="@string/dialogtxt_OK"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_txt"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a difference in dialogs sizes? Is logout dialog - a small dialog and `dialog_podaj` - a full screen one?

Comment: all dialogs are around same size and are just normal dialogues....
I have done similar application ones. And have the same code (I can say that it is almost copy-pasted), and in this old application, dialog windows works perfectly. 
Just at that one activity Android Studio don't want to cooperate and don't show a dialog window...
Can it be because of guidelines, I think? This is the only difference I can see. 
(Sorry for my english, this is not my native language...)

Comment: it is not the guideline fault (I checked this)

Comment: @M.Deer - Can you provide your feedback on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61640563/10819573)? I hope it worked for you.